# Is Earth the same size as the Riverworld?

Tags: riverworld

Philip José Farmer's [Riverworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverworld) book series takes place on a terraformed planet with a single river system that flows between 10 & 20 million miles from begining to end and tightly zig zags through a vastly tall mountain edged valley that houses a population of 36,006,009,637 souls. It doesn't have a moon and the night sky is different than the one seen from Earth, so it *probably* isn't our planet.

Is it ever revealed in any of the Riverworld books, [PC games](http://www.mobygames.com/game/windows/philip-jos-farmers-riverworld/mobyrank) or [movies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1419950/) how big this terraformed planet is compared to Earth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the average width is 9 miles, the length is 20 million miles, that gives an approximate area of 180 million square miles. The area of earth is 510.072 million sq km, or about 196 million square miles. So it at least makes sense that the area is approximately that of earth.

As far as the gradient goes, I would imagine most of it would be as gentle as can be. From [this article](http://www.durangobill.com/GCriverProfile.html) on the Colorado river, the section at a lake is roughly a gradient of a fraction of a foot per mile. This is at a lake, Lake Mead. Presumably the flow of the River would be very gentle, as the entire planet was purposefully made. Still, this would indicate that the mountains would be higher than on earth, even just 1 inch per mile would lead to the source being 315 miles high. There are several ways to get around this, Burton in the first novel surmises a manipulation of gravity (see quote).  But I believe it could be done, and that a such a river would be on a planet roughly the size of Earth, although the entire concept has a few holes in it, if you look closely enough.

Quote from 'Riverworld", the first book 'To your scattered bodies go'

> And how did The River flow uphill?
>
> Its rate of speed seemed to remain constant even where it should have slowed or refused to go further. From this he postulated localized gravitational fields that urged the mighty stream onward until it had regained an area where natural gravity would take over.

Comment: I wish I had the width of the mountian ranges to factor in. The barriers are tall, but I don't recall how wide they are.

Comment: Pearsonartphoto, just curious if you think that taking into account the height of the planet should take precedence over the area? I first did the same calculation that you did, but then realized that in order for the river to have any sort of discernible flow that it would need to start ridiculously high.

Comment: The height would greatly increase the area though wouldn't it?

Comment: I believe in the first novel Burton suggests or is presented with the possibility of a gravity fluctuation at some point(s) along the river. This causes the river to flow upstream and eliminate the need for a 315 mile elevation change.  I will try to remember to look for the quote this evening.

Answer (score -2):

To get an idea I compared the figure you gave for the length of the river to our longest river, the Nile. I conclude that **it is much larger than the Earth.**

The Nile is only 4,132 miles long. That means that the river from the series is approximately **2400 to 4800 times longer**.

The Niles highest elevation is approximately 1.6 miles, but even if it were only half a mile high at its highest, that would give an average drop of 0.64 feet per mile of river. That would mean that the river from the series would drop a total of 1212 to 2424 **miles** in elevation. The highest peak on Earth above sea level is approximately 5.5 miles.

Comment: I think you are assuming that the River of Riverworld is a natural phenomenon, like the rivers of Earth. That clearly isn't the case.

Comment: @DJClayworth The only assumption I was making is that it flows according to gravity...I.e. from an area of high elevation to low elevation. Even if it only dropped 0.01 feet per mile (0.12 inches), it would still start at 37 *miles* in elevation, 10 times higher than the highest peak on Earth. It would have to drop at only approximately 0.01 inches per mile to start at an elevation of 3.7 miles, which I find highly unlikely.